# Meaning of "Lakshmi murti(moorti) mantra"?

Tags: mantras, idols

I know what "moorti" means in Sanskrit. But what does a moorti mantra mean? For example, Lakshmi murti mantra- does it mean a mantra for the deity to manifest in corporeal form? Please clarify.

This term I came across in "Lakshmi Tantra" with translation:
https://archive.org/stream/laksmitantratranslationbysanjuktaguptareprintdelhi2003lakshmitantra/LAKSMI-TANTRA-translation-by-Sanjukta-Gupta-reprint-Delhi-2003-LAKSHMI-TANTRA_djvu.txt

Comment: Where did you hear about this term? Can you give us a link?

Comment: The key words should be murti-mantra, by the way.

Comment: Ok thanks for giving the link